# Equivalence classes of the join of two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces. Then $X\star Y$ is the quotient of $X\times[0,1]\times Y$ by the equivalence relation generated by $(x,0,y)\sim(x,0,y')$ and $(x,1,y)\sim(x',1,y)$. Let $\pi$ denote the canonical surjection of $X\times[0,1]\times Y$ onto $X\star Y$. For $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, we have $\pi(x,0,y)=X\times0\times Y$ and $\pi(x,1,y)= X\times 1\times Y$. For $\alpha\in(0,1)$, is there an explicit description of $\pi(x,\alpha,y)$?

Comment: What does $\pi(x,0,y)=X\times0\times Y$ mean? I am confused

Comment: The join is formed by drawing a line segment from each point $x$ of $X$ to each point $y$ of $Y$. So for example $\pi(x, 1/2, y)$ is the point halfway between $x$ and $y$ on the line joining them.

Comment: In connection with John Palmieri’s comment you might find the illustration in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)) helpful.